# Union expression background color SSRS 2012

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, background-color, ssrs-2012

I have a ssrs report
the report contains 2 tables

`Table 1` contains an expression for background color cells:

```
=iif((Fields!FIO.Value.ToString() like "*high*")
or (Fields!FIO.Value.ToString() like "*temp*"),"#ff8989", "White" )
```

`Table 2` contains an expression for background color cells

```
=iif(Fields!Fields.Value < 0, "#A1e7cf", "White")
```

I want to add expression to the current expressions: `=Iif(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2, "LightGrey" , "Transparent")`
but I do not know how to unite them, Google could not help me.

how to union 2 expressions for `table 1`:

```
=iif((Fields!FIO.Value.ToString() like "*high*")
or (Fields!FIO.Value.ToString() like "*temp*"),"#ff8989", "White" )
AND
=Iif(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2, "LightGrey" , "Transparent")
```

for `table 2`

```
=iif(Fields!Fields.Value < 0, "#A1e7cf", "White")
AND
=Iif(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2, "LightGrey" , "Transparent")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your syntax is correct, you could combine the logic like this:

```
=Switch(Fields!FIO.Value.ToString() like "high" or Fields!FIO.Value.ToString() like "temp", "#ff8989"
, RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2, "LightGrey"
, true , "White" ) 

=Switch(Fields!Fields.Value < 0, "#A1e7cf", "White"
, RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2, "LightGrey"
, true , "Transparent")
```

A `Switch` is like a series of `IIf` statements. It has pairs of conditions and results. The result for the first true condition will be selected. You can follow this pattern to adjust the behavior as needed.